# WiFi Module breaks when nobody is looking at it. (or: Schrodingers WiFi)

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, pm2

I come to you guys with a strange problem.

For our project, we're using NodeJS on a Raspberry Pi3 (running Raspbian). We build a wifi module using the following library: [WifiControl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wifi-control). For monitoring the logs of the application on the Raspberry Pi, we use pm2. For entering the SSID and password that the Pi needs to connect to, we have a little GUI interface running that allows the user to send these details to the Pi.

The case is as follows:

- When the user enters their SSID and password
- It is send to the Pi3
- The pi3 uses the library to attempt to connect to the provided AP
- The pi informs the GUI of the status of the connection attempt (success/ failed)

This works fine, IF we are watching the Pi's logs with pm2 during the connection attempt (we ssh into the Pi and then use pm2 logs). The Pi always connects to the wifi (assuming the credentials input were correct) when we use it this way.

Now, if we repeat the exact same steps as above, but this time we don't ssh into the Pi and track what's going on, the Pi is never able to connect. What could be causing this "schrodingers wifi", where observing the connection attempt means it works, and not observing it means it doesn't? Below I have added the logs from pm2 during 2 different connection attempts. The lines prefixed with 'WifiControl' are debug output from the library.

Output during observation of connection attempt:

```
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:46 +00:00: [2017-11-02T10:46:05.709Z] [WIFI]: Trying to connect to: { ssid: 'ssid', password: 'password' }
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:46 +00:00: WiFiControl: It appears there is already a connection for this SSID.
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:46 +00:00: WiFiControl: Executing:   nmcli connection delete "ssid"
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:46 +00:00: WiFiControl: Success!
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:46 +00:00: WiFiControl: Executing:   nmcli device wifi connect "ssid" password "password"
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:46 +00:00: WiFiControl: Success!
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:46 +00:00: WiFiControl: WiFi connection request to "ssid" has been processed.
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:46 +00:00: WiFiControl: Successfully connected to "ssid"
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:46 +00:00: [2017-11-02T10:46:09.681Z] [WIFI]: Successfully connected to: Onmi Airspace
1|OCB-RN3K | [2017-11-02T10:46:09.682Z] [CONTROLS]: WiFi Connected!
```

Output after not observing the connection attempt:

```
[WIFI]: Trying to connect to: { ssid: 'ssid', password: 'password' }
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:48 +00:00: WiFiControl: Executing:   nmcli device wifi connect "ssid" password "password"
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:48 +00:00: WiFiControl: WiFi connection request to "ssid" has been processed.
1|OCB-RN3K | 2017-11-02 10:48 +00:00: [2017-11-02T10:48:56.737Z] [WIFI]: Error during connection attempt [1/3]: { ssid: 'ssid',
1|OCB-RN3K |   success: false,
1|OCB-RN3K |   msg: 'Error: Could not connect to ssid' }
```

This has been tested multiple times, and we believe this is not a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appeared not to be related to pm2 logs, but some missing permissions on the Raspberry Pi. This meant that when we SSH'd into the Pi, we would login and trigger the right permissions for this user allowing nmcli to function (even though the program runs on startup logged in as the same user we use during ssh).

EDIT: The following did not work after all:

> The problem was resolved by granting sudo privileges to the user that
>   the program runs on, and we're now looking into other options
>   regarding the permissions (as sudo is a bit overzealous). I'm leaving
>   this question up for further reference, as this was a very hard to
>   narrow down bug.